# An object for every sprite? (Games, OOP)

Tags: oop, object, sprite

Currently I am trying my best programming a little video game in the style of the old Zelda games. However, I am having some trouble with the whole OOP style of thinking. To be more specific, I don't really know how to "design" the screens.

Let's say I have a class for my sprites and loaded a Wall-sprite to have a border for a certain area, should I make an extra "wall"-class, or is the wall being a "sprite" already enough? I thought it might be senseless to define an extra class since it would not have any different variables than the actual sprite class (as my wall IS only a sprite) so I didn't consider it to be a useful idea.

I am asking this because I have a little problem with the collision detection as well: What I currently do is loading a sprite for an object only once and rendering it multiple times at several locations. But the problem is that this causes the collision only to be detected at the last position the sprite was rendered at.

It gives me more problems when I render 2 cave-entrances somewhere but my game only checks for the 2nd entrance if I "entered" it.

So I thought making an extra "entrance"-class and creating 2 completely different objects of it that are treated separately might help, but should I then also create 30 objects for my wall-sprites?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ might be a better forum for you for this type of question.

Comment: @DonBottstein when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: I know this question is a little general, but there is a good specific question buried in there. However, @DonBottstein is right in the future this sort of post would be better located on the programmers site.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, there is really two questions, well three, but the OOP-thinking is too non-specific for a good question.  So let's see if we can answer it by answering your  valid ones.

Good OO Design is centered around "Patterns" (Common solutions to a variety of Problems) in the case of your sprite re-use in OO this would be known as a "Fly-weight" Pattern. Three important structural elements in good OO and understanding them is key to "getting it". They are:

Interfaces - They are free (relatively) of operational code, and provide only method and constructor signatures(generally) to allow for clean separation of coding concerns.

Classes - Only the reusable parts(ideally) of an object they are "the Mold or Pattern" that objects are instantiated (or patterned) from.

Objects - Instances (this chair or that chair as opposed, to Chair as an ideal) of the same form of Class (the ideal Chair). Objects (ideally) should keep as instance values only that which differentiates it from other instances of the same ideal.

However, because your original sprite is not an object you are having this collision problem, because it actually is the same instance rendered again and again, the graphics pipeline does not keep all of its previous locations as separate things it actual just stores pixels(usually), once they've been translated.

In this case if each instance is an object, each instance would have its location as a local instance variable(s), while its graphical representation and collision detection method would be common to all instances of the class.

Don't think of it as having 30 whole copies in memory at once, you only have thirty copies of the instance variables.  This is true if you use OO or not; in a procedural solution to get proper collision detection you would have to maintain an array of all of the places you rendered that sprite and iterate through each time, further your code would be less cleanly separated and you would have to iterate through the array for every sprite interaction as well as for updating moving sprites.  With OO you could handle this with one class method call that recurses it children.

A good class structure for this simple example might be:

An Abstract Sprite Class (abstract because you will never use a non-specific Sprite) containing only code common to all sprites

A Concrete Wall Sprite Class that extends Sprite, only the code for non-moving wall sprites.

A Concrete Trigger Sprite Class (whose graphic might be clear or null) for behaviors that need to be triggered in "open spaces"

A Concrete Agent Sprite Class for moving sprites (might implement a movable interface meaning all derivatives of the class have a move() method.

A Concrete Character class that extends agent for a movable sprite that is driven by user commands.

It may seem confusing at first, but it's actually cleaner, simpler, and more maintainable doing it the OO way.

:)

Comment: Thanks a lot! The iterating-through-an-array is actually exactly what I have been doing so far as my "solution", and I'm glad to know this seems to be  an actual "known" solution and I didn't do something completely strange. I am currently using a sprite class that has methods for loading and rendering animated and non-animated sprites,  I don't really know though how I would organize my level design without the array, since I always need to have some kind of coordinates to put the sprites at their respective place, could you explain that a little more?
Thanks a lot so far though! (: